# How can i protect my laravel authentication

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to protect them from viewing. That means without logging in it should not redirect to any other pages, if anyone tries to access, it should get back to login page.

I am using Laravel 5.4 and regular authentication

```
php artisan make:auth
```

And in login controller

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

And in Middleware RedirectifAuthenticated I am trying like this but it is not working.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
        return redirect('/leadsadd');
        return redirect('/leadslist');
        return redirect('/opporadd');
        return redirect('/opporlist');
        return redirect('/accadd');
        return redirect('/acclist');
        return redirect('/selftask');
 }

    return $next($request);

}
```

It's not working. I think the method I am doing is wrong. Can any one help how can I prevent it and should not redirect to any route or URL. 
**Route**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('leadsadd','crmcontroller@addleads');
Route::get('leadslist', 'crmcontroller@leadslist');
Route::any('leadview/{id}','crmcontroller@show');
Route::get('leadedit/{id}','crmcontroller@edit');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you redirecting to 8 different pages? You can only redirect once per request. This function will always redirect to `/home` if the user is logged in. All other returns are unreachable code.

Comment: no not like that i am telling we will be having different routes like(localhost:8000\add ,localhost:8000\view, localhost:8000\home, ) as specified above. Only when i am trying to access to localhost:8000\home it is redirecting to login page. but others are opening directly without any login request.

Comment: This should be defined in your routes file with a middleware. Can you show the contents of your `routes/web.php`?

Comment: i have done and edit to it. except for home page, for any other pages it is not redirecting to login page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [group your routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-groups) and add the `auth` middleware to it. this middleware will automatically redirect to the login page if any non-authenticated user tries to visit any of these pages.

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('leadsadd','crmcontroller@addleads');
    Route::get('leadslist', 'crmcontroller@leadslist');
    Route::any('leadview/{id}','crmcontroller@show');
    Route::get('leadedit/{id}','crmcontroller@edit');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this in your routes like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        // all authenticated users will have the access here! 
        ]]);
```

and your `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` should be revert back to original

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/yourdashboardorwhatever');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are following two ways to protect your routes in Laravel 5.4

One way is to attach the auth middleware with the route inside your web.php file

```
Route::get('profile', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');
```

The other way is to attach the middleware in the constructor of your controller that handles your route.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```